# Why am I getting "subscript out of range" when the subscript IS in the range?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working with some legacy spaghetti code that processes some hairy EDI.  Most of the code is indecipherable and has no indentation or comments or even good variable names but there's one line that gives me trouble when I remove the `On Error Resume Next` statement which causes the script to always timeout.

```
If UBound(arylin) >= 1 Then
    Do Until arylin(0) = "PB" and arylin(1) = "DEF"
        ' Processing goes here - not relevant for this
    Loop
End If
```

The script executes the conditional but errors at the "Do Until" line, saying:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' 

Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]'
```

Now, why on Earth would this be giving an error if I'm testing the upper bound before checking it, and it's saying that the upper bound is at least 1?

I can post more of the code if I have to but I'd rather not since my predecessor was a complete hack and the code is extremely ugly.

Comment: not really sure but, doesn't arrays in VBScript start with 1 and not with 0 ?

Comment: Most collections in VBScript are 0 based, but not all.

Comment: This one's zero-based, because I tried changing it to 1 and it now errored out at a later part of the code that was accessing arylin(2).  Not entirely sure since I've never looked at this piece of code before; users are complaining it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: Basically I changed it from arylin(0) and arylin(1) to arylin(1) and arylin(2) and it told me that 2 was out of range, but doing UBound returns 2

Comment: I also just tested via Response.Write indices 0 and 1 just before the loop, and they both have values!

Comment: Are you sure the array variable is not modified/re-assigned during the processing in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UBound()` returns the index of the last element in the array.  By default, arrays in vb languages prior to vb.net start at 1 rather than 0 (meaning the count and the index are normally the same thing, though you can change the default with `Option Base`).

Put those together you'll see that it's failing here:

```
arylin(0) = "PB"
```

Comment: Arrays create in VBScript always start at 0 and VBScript does not support Option Base.  However VBScript does support SAFEARRAY of variants that may have non-zero LBound values.  Many VB based COM components return 1 based arrays.

Answer (score 3):

See AnthonyWJones comment)
*(With VB you can set the base of arrays to start at either 0 or 1 - it should be at or near the top of a module: look for Option Base 1 or Option Base 0.)*

LBound will always return 0.*(You can also use LBound() to check the lower boundary of the array.)* 
(Just goes to show: don't expect MS to be consistent!)

Although you check that the array-size is >= 1 - which will ensure that arylin(0) is valid, but not necessarily arylin(1). The index is zero-based so if one element exists, it will be at index=0, and index=1 will be out-of-bounds.

You must check that the array-size >= 2 in this case. If you use two entries following each other consistently, then the check must be made for (array-size) mod 2 = 0.

Also make sure what value UBound actually returns. I googled and got contradicting information: [this](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_ubound.asp) says it returns the 'count' while [this one](http://www.empinstitute.org/caspdoc/html/vbscript_ubound_function.htm) says it returns the physical limit (= 'count' -1).

About the 'On Error Resume Next' thing, [maybe it should stay there](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/53760-checking-status-array) ...

Comment: Option Base not supported in VBScript

Comment: Re: `UBound`, straight from the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28VS.84%29.aspx), "Returns the **largest available subscript** for the indicated dimension of an array." (emphasis mine)